# How to handle Update error: Transaction does not have authorization for mytable3:mytable3.5?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, openlayers

I am building collaborative mapping app using openlayers 5.3.0, geoserver 2.14.0 and postgresql 10.4.
I want the user to be able to update features using wfs-t but before updating, the user needs to lock the feature so that no other users can update this feature before the first transaction committed to the db **(actually don't know if this should be handled manually or geoserver will handle it itself)**...

This is the lock feature request:

```
$.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs', {
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      service: 'WFS',
      version: '1.1.0',
      request: 'LockFeature',
      typename: 'mytable3',
      cql_filter: 'id=' + f.values_.id
    }
  });
```

And after this request Iam trying to update the feature using this request:

```
$.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/TOTO1/mytable3/wfs', {
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'xml',
  processData: false,
  contentType: 'text/xml',
  data: str,
}).done(function () {
  WFSsource.clear();
});
```

the update feature request without the lock works properly but when I use the lock the update feature request return with:

```
    <ows:ExceptionText>Update error: Transaction does not have authorization for mytable3:mytable3.5</ows:ExceptionText>
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format.

Comment: it looks like the 2nd request is not using the transaction with the lock - but I've never bothered with locking as it is designed for updates which will take a long (>1h) time

Comment: Looks like your GeoServer user doesn't have permissions to execute a WFS 
transaction. Check your geoserver log to see the full error and provide it.

Comment: @IanTurton that's true the 2nd request is independent from the first one, but is there a place says that locking is designed for (>1h) long updates??and if not how the 2nd request should be??

Comment: @pavlos No I am able to execute insert, update, delete using WFS-t...